# selectize.js questions about a no result plugin and allowing default behaviour on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)  for an auto suggest field, and i have used one of the [no_results](https://gist.github.com/antitoxic/9156ae5a4531fce46ad1) plugins to show a link when there is no result, and this works great for the most part, but i have a few dramas i am just not sure how to get around

I have two things i need to get help with

**1st most important - How to pass variables to the plugin** 
I have multiple instances of selectize on the several pages, so i need to pass the vars *hr_link* and *hr_label* to the plugin so i don't have to recreate the plugin 30 times with just the those vars different

**2nd - Allow link to be clicked, bypassing default behaviour** 
To get the links to be clickable i have used the *onmousedown()* and *touchstart()* but is there a better way to re-enable the default click on just this link in the results box.

I have spent a lot of time researching these items, so I don't think it is a duplicate

// The Plugin

```
    Selectize.define('header_no_results', function( options ) {
        var KEY_LEFT      = 37;
        var KEY_UP        = 38;
        var KEY_RIGHT     = 39;
        var KEY_DOWN      = 40;
        var ignoreKeys = [KEY_LEFT, KEY_UP, KEY_RIGHT, KEY_DOWN];
        var self = this;

        var hr_link =  'http://link_to_info.com';
        var hr_label = 'country';



        options = $.extend({
            message: ' No results found:  <a href="#" onmousedown="window.open(\''+hr_link+'\'); return false;" touchstart="window.open(\''+hr_link+'\'); return false;"> click here </a> to add a'+hr_label,
            html: function(data) {
                return '<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">' + data.message + '</div>';

            }
        }, options );


        self.on('type', function() {
            var message = 'Not Found: <a href="#" onmousedown="window.open(\''+hr_link+'\'); return false;" touchstart="window.open(\''+hr_link+'\'); return false;"> click here </a> Add a '+hr_label;
            if (!self.hasOptions) {
                self.$empty_results_container.html(message).show();

            } else {
                self.$empty_results_container.hide();
            }
        });


        self.onKeyUp = (function() {
            var original = self.onKeyUp;

            return function ( e ) {
                if (ignoreKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) return;
                self.isOpen = false;
                original.apply( self, arguments );
            }
        })();

        self.onBlur = (function () {
            var original = self.onBlur;

            return function () {
                original.apply( self, arguments );
                self.$empty_results_container.hide();
            };
        })();

        self.setup = (function() {
            var original = self.setup;
            return function() {
                original.apply( self, arguments);
                self.$empty_results_container = $(
                    options.html($.extend({
                        classNames: self.$input.attr( 'class' )
                    }, options))
                );
                self.$empty_results_container.hide();
                self.$dropdown.append(self.$empty_results_container);
            };
        })();
    });
```

// the function calling the plugin

```
    $('#companyLinks').selectize({

        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'display',
        searchField: 'display',
        maxItems: 1,
        options: [],
        create: false,
        onItemAdd: function(value){
            window.location.href = 'http://my_link.com/'+value;
        },
        load: function(query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://link.com/get/list',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    q: query
                },
                error: function() {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    callback(res);
                    //window.open($(res).val(), '_self');
                }
            });
        },

        plugins: ['header_no_results']


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to pass the var was not all that hard after all just had to look in the right place, and there is further info [here](https://github.com/brianreavis/microplugin.js#loading-plugins)

In the function we need to change out

```
 plugins: ['header_no_results']
```

with

```
plugins: { "header_no_results": {
            link : "page/location",
        } }
```

then we can retrieve **link** and declare the var we needed in the plugin by

```
var hr_link =  options.link;
```